# What scaffold generator was used in the Live Validations demo screencast?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator

In http://vimeo.com/3385181 Live Validations are demoed with what appears to be a standard scaffold-generated rails app. However, the styling is different (nicer) than that created by the standard rails scaffold generators.

What generator was used to make the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely (you don't actually see live scaffolding) that these forms have a CSS style-sheet other than the basic scaffold sheet attached and that some formatting has been done.

For example, there is a 'scaffolded' check box for the terms of service which, as far as I know, cannot be done with the RoR scaffolding tool.